# Continuity of $f-g$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-writing

I have seen the proof using the triangle inequality to show that if $f,g$ are continuous at say L, then so is $f+g$. I am curious as to how the proof would change for the case of $f-g$ using epsilon and deltas. How would the triangle inequality apply here? Or does subtraction only hold for existence of limits and not continuity?

Comment: It still remains true that $|f-g| \leq |f| + |g|$.

Comment: The fastest way is to observe that $f-g=f+(-g)$ and $|-g|=|g|$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see almost no difference: $|(f-g)(x)-(f-g)(y)|=|f(x)-f(y)-[g(x)-g(y)]|\leq|f(x)-f(y)|+|g(x)-g(y)|$. Note that $|a-b|\leq|a|+|b|$ still holds.

Comment: Well, if both $f$ and $g$  each have the same limit L, then don't we have something like |$(f-g)(x)-L$|? How can this be broken up?

Comment: If they have the same limit, then the limit of $f-g$ at $x$ is zero, because of $|f(x)-g(x)|\leq|f(x)-L|+|g(x)-L|$ and the latter can be approximated arbitrarily small.

Comment: Or rather, if they both continuous at L this still holds?

Comment: Yes, same trick again.